# whether or not usage

Tags: grammar

Waiting for the answer whether or not configuration changes helped?

I am struggling with the second part of the question. Does this sentence correct or i need to change it?

Comment: No, you need a preposition between *"answer"* and *"whether"*. Voting to close because this is proofreading, which is off-topic.

Comment: *"**I am** waiting for **an** answer **regarding** whether or not **the** configuration changes helped"*.

Comment: The elephant in the room is that this is not a question. It is a declarative sentence. The question mark has no business being there.

Answer (score 1):

The word **whether** indicates that there is a choice or a doubt between two alternatives. After whether, the words "or not" are necessary in some cases.

If the words **or not** are omitted, there will probably be a statement of alternatives connected by **or**.

E.g. Whether he leaves or stays is of absolutely no importance to me.

The New York Times Manual of Style and Usage (Random House, 1999, p.355) says that **“when a whether clause modifies a *verb*, *or not* is needed:**

E.g. They’ll play tomorrow whether or not it rains.

(The clause with *whether* modifies ‘play.’)”

E.g. I’ll call you tomorrow whether I have the answer for you then or not.

(The clause with *whether* modifies “call.”)

Answer (score 1):

Here’s what The **Times’s stylebook** says:

The phrase may ordinarily be omitted in these cases:

• When the whether clause is the **object of a verb**:

She wonders whether the teacher will attend.

(The clause is the object of wonders.)

• When the clause is the **object of a preposition**:

The teacher will base his decision on whether the car has been repaired.

(The clause is the object of on.)

• When the clause is the **subject of the sentence:**

Whether the car will be ready depends on the mechanic.

(The clause is the subject of depends.)

But when a whether clause modifies a verb, ***or not is needed***:

They will play tomorrow whether or not it rains.

(The clause modifies play.)

=> Put more briefly, “whether” can generally stand alone when its clause is functioning as a noun, but not when the clause is serving as an adverb.